# On Running app Android Studio showing no device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I started working on android after a gap of about four months yesterday. I updated it and have resolved some issues. When I created a simple login form and google map in new application I wanted to test it **But** when I run, the app dialog do not show any device check out this

[image]

I tried it more than five times with restarting the `android studio` but it does not show anything. I have two devices created one today with `API 24` in `AVD Manager`  check out this

[image]

And one device in [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) is also running So, I wanna know why these are not appearing when I click <kbd>Run</kbd> button?

what should I do to show these in here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `adb` hasn't started, there is no device to run. You can start via `adb start-server`

Comment: @adnbsr According to Task manager `adb.exe` is running.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer options in your phone.

Comment: I'm using emulator as mentioned above.

Comment: You created emulator device?

Comment: have you read my question ?... a picture also state that 2 devices I have already created